# Elegant way to create a failed deferred with a stacktrace?

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted

I'm implementing a function that is supposed to return a deferred. Inside that function I decide that an error happened.

I could just raise the error:

```
raise ValueError("...")
```

but then the function is not returning a deferred anymore. I don't want to use `maybeDeferred` anytime I call it.

Alternatively, I could return a deferred like this:

```
return defer.fail(Failure(ValueError(...)))
```

This works, but the `Failure` won't include a stacktrace, making it hard to track the error down.

The best thing I found so far is this:

```
try:
    raise ValueError("...")
except:
    return defer.fail()
```

I get a deferred back and the `Failure` contains the stacktrace. But this is rather verbose.

**Is there a better way that I'm missing?**

I'm a bit surprised that such a common thing hasn't an elegant solution.

Comment: What is inelegant about this?  The stacktrace is what shows where an exception is thrown, so you throw an exception and then create the Deferred.  Seems pretty straightforward to me…

Comment: @Glyph Four lines for what should be one. Raising an exception just to catch it immediately. I would have expected something like the second example, but with twisted adding the stacktrace for me. Of course, "elegant" and "better" are subjective. I guess should have asked for "one-liner" instead to stay closer to stackoverflow's creed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question surprised me a little, and I had to think for a while about why.

If all you want is for the failure with traceback to bubble up and get logged by the global error handler, you needn't return a `defer.fail()`. Raising the exception will get that behavior.

The difference would be in a situation like this:

```
foo().addErrback(fooErrorHandler)
```

in that case, `fooErrorHandler` would get called when the result of the deferred was a failure but **not** when it was an exception raised synchronously. That would require this more cumbersome form:

```
try:
    foo().addErrback(fooErrorHandler)
except Exception, err:
    fooErrorHandler(Failure(err))
```

which admittedly looks pretty bad. But the situation we're talking about is now a case where

1. you define an explicit error handler for this call
2. the error handler does something with the failure's traceback
3. the function can fail synchronously *or* asynchronously
4. You use the same error handler for both the synchronous and asynchronous failure modes.

which is maybe why it hasn't come up as such a common thing as you might think.

Of course, the other reason it might not have come up as a common thing is that people are often lazy about defining error handlers, and often lazy about documenting the sorts of exceptions their code may raise.

Ah-hah, something else that may have added to my confusion: `Failure` *does* know how to to store its stack, but it was explicitly changed to [not do this unless there's a traceback](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/changeset/6476) for performance reasons. The method described by that commit message to get a traceback is the same as the four-line try/except example in your post.

I guess that could be an option to `Failure()` (as `captureVars` is), or an alternate constructor method, if this does come up enough to warrant it.

Comment: I agree with your analysis. The situation should be more common than it is in practice. I consider the differentiation between sync and async failures (and results) an implementation detail. In accordance with "Information hiding" I want to provide the caller with a unified API. Thank you for the link. That makes it clear that the third solution is the preferred one. Not really Python-Zen to have a default behaviour that trades performance for clarity, though.